# Type "p" Annotations with Plain Text files

Tags: gate

I am trying to understand whether GATE is able to extract annotations of type "p" from plain text files which are UTF-8 encoded.

HTML files and PDF files work just fine and "p" annotations are added when these 2 file types are being analysed.

I tried using different PRs but i do not seem to be able to get type "p" annotations under Original Markups.

Is there a way to achieve this for Plain Text files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Annotation Set Transfer PR which will move "p" annotations from Original Markups to Default set. Then you will be able to use them according to your requirements.

Comment: I think this is not possible since i do not get any "p" Type annotations from Original markups when GATE analyses Text files.

Comment: Absolutely empty Original Markups? I think at least one must be there for plain text. GATE has a code which tries to find paragraphs based on some rules for new lines(as far as I remember based on r\n and etc). As an option you could write your own JAPE rule for paragraphs detection.